# Specify Indexes on node properties during neo4j-import

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible in using the neo4j import tool to specify properties of nodes that will need an index created on them?  Currently, I import then run a set of `Create Index on :somelable(someproperty)` statements, but this isn't the fastest with large data sets.

Comment: You should explain what is not fast, i.e. the queries and the resulting query-plan (you can get it by prefixing your query with PROFILE).

Comment: @MichaelHunger  Maybe 'fast' is the wrong word choice. I mean the multi step process with a number of different indexes to create isn't optimal.   Ideally you'd be able to provide a file at import time with the indexes you want like `neo4j-import --nodes node.csv --indexes indexlist.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, as of v2.2.3.  When you use the super fast import tool (`neo4j-import`), you must setup Indexes once you've imported the nodes and relationships.

Comment: You can use neo4j-shell afterwards to setup the indexes and then use `schema await` to block it from ending until the indexes (and constraints) are done.